# How to set up route in java that uses bean references

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to set up the following route:

```
  @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        log.info("Creating ftp rout from " + config.ftpUrl().split("\\?")[0]);
        from(config.ftpUrl()
             + "&stepwise=true"
             + "&delay=1000"
             + "&move=${file:name}.trans"
             + "&recursive=true"
             + "&binary=true"
             + "&filter=#" + Beans.doneFilter.name()
             + "&maxMessagesPerPoll=200"
             + "&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false"
             + "&sorter=#" + Beans.sorter.name())
                                                     .log("Downloading file ${file:name}")
                                                     .to("file:" + config.ftpTargetPostpaid())
                                                     .to("file:" + config.ftpTargetPrepaid())
                                                     .to("file:" + config.ftpTargetFonic())
                                                     //.routePolicyRef(Beans.policy.name())
                                                     .autoStartup(false)
                                                     .routeId("ftp");
    }
```

The error is:

> Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't
>   a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion
>   possible: No type converter available to convert from type:
>   java.lang.String to the required type:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value
>   #doneFilter

I think the way i reference a bound bean is wrong? I bound all beans this way(stand alone app):

```
public class MainApp {

/**
 * A main() so we can easily run these routing rules in our IDE
 */
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new CepModule());
    Main main = new Main();
    bindBeans(main);
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(i.getInstance(FetchFtp.class));
    main.run();

}

private static void bindBeans(Main main) {
    for (Beans bean : Beans.values()) {
        main.bind(bean.name(), bean.clazz());
    }
}

/**
 * This is the java style bean registry. Use the enums name as reference to the bean.
 * 
 *
 */
public static enum Beans{
    sorter(SortingStrategy.class),
    policy(PolicyForStartAndStopRoutes.class),
    doneFilter(ExcludeDoneFilesFilter.class);

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    Beans(Class<?> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;;
    }

    public Class<?> clazz(){
        return clazz;
    }
}

}
```

So how to use beans/classes in routes configured in java?

Comment: Have you registered a bean that implements GenericFileFilter with the name doneFilter?

Comment: yeah the doneFilter implements it - the hole route works fine using xml but i try to "convert" is to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel expects not only `class` references but bean instances.

Assuming the classes have a default constructor, bind `bean.clazz().newInstance()` to the registry instead of `bean.clazz()`, i. e.:

```
main.bind(bean.name(), bean.clazz().newInstance());
```