# Using custom registries within apache camel

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel, javabeans

Apache Camel does not seem to support any bean that is to be used within its registry. I am currently trying to add an AWS S3 Client object/bean to the spring configuration without any luck. The bean itself is added to the registry, but when camel goes to use the client object it throws an error similar to this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 
suitable setter for property: amazonS3Client as there isn't a setter  method 
with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type 
converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the 
required type: com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 with value 
#amazonClient
```

The amazonClient is the aforementioned bean that is added appropriately the spring config which has led me to believe the camel config is indeed finding the bean. Here is the related xml configuration:

```
<!-- set up default amazon s3 client from amazon aws sdk -->
<bean id="amazonClient" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
            <constructor-arg name="accessKey" value=""/>
            <constructor-arg name="secretKey" value=""/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Within the camel context section (you can see the bean is mentioned):

```
    <camel:route id="importFilesFromS3">
        <camel:from uri="aws-s3://intuit-commerce-imports?amazonS3Client=#amazonClient&amp;region=us-west-2&amp;deleteAfterRead=true"/>
        <camel:to uri="ref:importProcessingEndpoint"/>
    </camel:route>
```

Apache camel claims to have this feature in their [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/aws-s3.html), but I have found a few sources that come across the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015179/how-to-set-up-route-in-java-that-uses-bean-references). The answer in the link does not provide much explanation.

Comment: Possible side effect of the AWS S3 [shortage](https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/?ncid=rss) ?

Comment: Nah. Its been persistent this past week. Good catch though.

Comment: Can you share you how you added it to spring? I added beans in blueprint and that works. Should be similar.

Comment: I have added the applicable configuration. Let me know if you would like anything else, however, I dont think this configuration is the issue. Since I can see the bean is added to the registry, I believe camel is having issues using this type of bean.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with AWS S3, but I also ran into a similar problem with Camel seemingly not able to find the bean within the Spring registry.

By stepping through IntrospectionSupport.setProperty, I noticed that CamelContextHelper.lookup was using JndiRegistry instead of the ApplicationContextRegistry.

My solution was to add camel-spring as a project dependency, as well as to initialize my camel context with ApplicationContextRegistry:

```
camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(new ApplicationContextRegistry(applicationContext));
```